# Unity3d 4.5.5f1 "Build and Run" not rendering properly, but works in Editor

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have a simple scene with a Terrain object, trees, detail, water and fog. In the editor it renders exactly as expected:

[image: Editor Render]

But when I build it and run, it comes out sans textures, lighting or really any shaders:

[image: http://i.imgur.com/7JZvygd.png]

I'm sure it's something silly I'm missing, but I searched other questions first and didn't find any with solutions that worked for me.

Any ideas what's happening here?

Comment: It is probably your build settings. I can't say more without more information.

Comment: What additional information would you like? I've tried it on 2 different GPUs, one integrated one dedicated. I'm building windows x86. I've tried Dev and not.

Comment: Are you using DirectX build? Are you using Vertex lit?

Comment: I'm forcing dx11 with -force-d3d11. Unity crashes if I don't.

Comment: That lead me to the answer! Thanks! It turns out I had forgotten to check "Use Direct3D 11" in the shared build settings.

Comment: I feel like posting that as the answer now :P

Comment: Please do. I'll mark it :P

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check that you are using DirectX on the build. Make sure it says "Use Direct3d 11" in the shared build settings.

[image]